# Trouble using saveACopy with group layers

Tags: python, arcpy, layers

This code works fine on layers in the TOC that are not group layers, but errrors out if there are any group layers in the TOC.

```
import arcpy, re, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#loop through layers and save a copy

def layer_save(mxd_path,path):

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    fcs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)
    for item in fcs:
        formatted = str(item).replace("/","-")
        item.saveACopy(str(path) + "\\" + formatted + ".lyr")       

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #variables
    mxd_p = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    path_lyrs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    #kickoff
    layer_save(mxd_p,path_lyrs)
```

Comment: Some more information would help. What errors, specifically? What is the objective of the code?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the problem I was running into. I was accidentally entering 'item == item.longName' rather than 'item.name == item.longName' which was resulting in the same name rather than a different one. Here is the working code:

```
import arcpy, re, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#loop through layers and save a copy

def layer_save(mxd_path,path):

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    fcs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)
    exported = 0
    for item in fcs:        
        if item.isGroupLayer:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Group Layer")
            arcpy.AddMessage(str(item.name))
            formatted = re.sub(r'[/\\]', '-', str(item.name))
            item.saveACopy(str(path) + "\\" + formatted + ".lyr")
            exported += 1

        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Regular Layer")
            arcpy.AddMessage(str(item.name))
            if str(item.name) == str(item):
                formatted = re.sub(r'[/\\]', '-', str(item))
                item.saveACopy(str(path) + "\\" + formatted + ".lyr")
                exported += 1
            else:
                pass

    arcpy.AddMessage("The total layers exported is: " + str(exported))    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #variables
    mxd_p = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    path_lyrs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    #kickoff
    layer_save(mxd_p,path_lyrs)
```

Comment: So str(item) is the same as item.longname?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the layer is a group layer with the isGroupLayer property.  This was instituted in 10.0.

See [this blog post](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.ca/2011/07/arcpy-looking-inside-group-layers.html).

Edit: Ok, Here's my second edit.  I found the answer [in the Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000008000000):

```
for item in fcs:
  if item.name != item.longname:
    continue
  formatted = ...
```

A layer's longname will also have the Group Layer name if the layer is in a group layer.  So checking to make sure they match will tell you if the layer is in a Group.  Not sure why the Groups aren't saving for you though.  What version of Arc were you using?

Comment: I don't want to skip group layers, I want to saveACopy just like the others. I also don't want to each sublayer of the group to become a saved layer as well.

Comment: Okay I added the isGroupLayer expression, how do I skip sub layers within the group?

Comment: I thought of doing what you posted above but my situation is a bit tricky, I want to saveACopy of the group layer only, and skip the sub layers. So I still need the actual group layer saved out.